# How to Copy Lightroom Preferences?

Tags: lightroom

How does one copy Lightroom preferences (not a Catalog) from one machine to another? Assume that both versions run on the same OS, in this case Windows 7 Pro 64-bits.

While I've had Lightroom for several years a few months ago I upgraded to 5.3 and just last week got a laptop. Since the license terms allow installation on two machines, I installed it there but find that it looks and works differently because of preferences for layout, display modes, treatment of import, etc. Such settings seem to be all-over-the-place in the UI, so it would be great if I can just copy them rather than checking each option one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Adobe's Lightroom help](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/preference-file-locations-lightroom-41.html), in Windows the preferences file is located at `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Lightroom\Preferences\Lightroom 5 Preferences.agprefs`.